# How to understand this reference to "after 30 days"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) contains this sentence.

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions
>   that have **negative score after 30 days**.

My question: What happens to an unanswered question that just got downvoted on the 32nd day?

Actually the unanswered question which I am talking about has zero votes, but on the 32nd day of the posting got downvoted by some user.

Comment: It seems that once 30 days have passed begininning with day 32, the system will delete the question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant It is very difficult to understand your comment right now, please post in clear manner, **I am not a native speaker**.

Comment: The system requires 30 consecutive days in which the question is unanswered and has a negative score. The count toward 30 days begins on the day when the question is downvoted. That can be day 32 or day 300, I imagine.

Comment: The example is purposely ambiguous, and can't be answered with certainty without more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example text is rather ambiguous and has been expanded. (It was from a compact list of summaries, intended more as a reminder than an actual precise guide, although this is not entirely clear in the text.) There are two major possibilities:

1. A thirty-day countdown begins immediately once the score becomes negative. That is, "after 30 days" applies to the time that the question *first qualifies*.
2. A thirty-day (or more) countdown begins when the question is asked and can only conclude once the score becomes negative. That is, "after 30 days" applies to the time the question is *asked*.

As it happens, the actual behavior being described is basically the second one. (There are some additional complications in practice because of the timing of the roomba runs.)